# fix-point combinators in clojure

Tags: clojure, fixpoint-combinators

One of my favorite ways to test the power of a language I'm learning is to try and implement various fixed-point combinators. Since I'm learning Clojure (though I'm not new to lisps), I did the same for it.

First, a little "testable" code, factorial:

```clj
(def !'
  "un-fixed factorial function"
  (fn [f]
    (fn [n]
      (if (zero? n)
        1
        (* n (f (dec n)))))))

(defn !
  "factorial"
  [n]
  (if (zero? n)
    1
    (apply * (map inc (range n)))))
```

For any combinator `c` I implement, I want to verify that `((c !') n)` is equal to `(! n)`.

We start with the traditional Y:

```clj
(defn Y
  "pure lazy Y combinator => stack overflow"
  [f]
  (let [A (fn [x] (f (x x)))]
   (A A)))
```

But of course Clojure is not nearly so lazy as that, so we pivot to Z:

```clj
(defn Z
  "strict fixed-point combinator"
  [f]
  (let [A (fn [x] (f (fn [v] ((x x) v))))]
   (A A)))
```

And indeed, it holds that `(= ((Z !') n) (! n))`.

Now comes my issue: I cannot get either of [U](http://matt.might.net/articles/church-encodings-demo-in-scheme/) or the Turing combinator (theta-v) to work correctly. I suspect with U it's a language limit, while with theta-v I'm more inclined to believe it's a misread of [Wikipedia's notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Fixed-point_combinators_in_lambda_calculus):

```
(defn U
  "the U combinator => broken???"
  [f]
  (f f))

(defn theta-v
  "Turing fixed-point combinator by-value"
  [f]
  (let [A (fn [x] (fn [y] (y (fn [z] ((x x) y) z))))]
    (A A)))
```

A sample REPL experience:

```clj
((U !') 5)
;=> Execution error (ClassCastException) at fix/!'$fn (fix.clj:55).
;=> fix$_BANG__SINGLEQUOTE_$fn__180 cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
((theta-v !') 5)
;=> Execution error (ClassCastException) at fix/theta-v$A$fn (fix.clj:36).
;=> java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
```

Can anyone explain

1. Why these implementations of U and theta-v are not working; and
2. How to fix them?

Comment: Please include a link to the code you are attempting to translate.

Comment: Er, @amalloy I'm translating math more than code, but if it helps, sure

Comment: FWIW a lot of math and code are the same thing. Certainly lambda calculus is both.

Comment: Small point: since `(*)` is `1`, you don't need `1` as a special case in function `!`. `(defn ! [n] (apply * (map inc (range n))))` works, as does `(defn ! [n] (reduce * (range 1 (inc n))))`, which I prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of theta-v is wrong for two reasons. The first is pretty obvious: you accept `f` as a parameter and then ignore it. A more faithful translation would be to use `def` style, as you have for your other functions:

```
(def theta-v
  "Turing fixed-point combinator by-value"
  (let [A (fn [x] (fn [y] (y (fn [z] ((x x) y) z))))]
    (A A)))
```

The second reason is a bit sneakier: you translated `λz.xxyz` to `(fn [z] ((x x) y) z)`, remembering that lisps need more parentheses to denote function calls that are implicit in lambda-calculus notation. However, you missed one set: just as `x x y z` would have meant "evaluate `x` twice, then `y` once, then finally return `z`", what you wrote means "evaluate `((x x) y)`, then throw away that result and return `z`". Adding the extra set of parentheses yields a working `theta-v`:

```
(def theta-v
  "Turing fixed-point combinator by-value"
  (let [A (fn [x] (fn [y] (y (fn [z] (((x x) y) z)))))]
    (A A)))
```

and we can demonstrate that it works by calculating some factorials:

```
user> (map (theta-v !') (range 10))
(1 1 2 6 24 120 720 5040 40320 362880)
```

As for U: to use the U combinator, functions being combined must change how they self-call, meaning you would need to rewrite `!'` as well:

```
(def U [f] (f f))

(def ! (U (fn [f]
            (fn [n]
              (if (zero? n)
                1
                (* n ((f f) (dec n))))))))
```

Note that I have changed **`(f (dec n))`** to **`((f f) (dec n))`**.

Comment: ack! I can't believe I missed that... theta starts with lambda.x, not lambda.f. Interesting that U requires this extra modification to its arguments. (PS agreed on the code/math thing, just wanted to clarify that i was translating from lambda calculus and not someone's python code or something)

Comment: Thanks for the article. Unfortunately, even with this correction to theta-v, I get `(map (fix/theta-v fix/fib') (range 10))
; (0 1 1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15)
(map fix/fib (range 10))
; (0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34)
(map (fix/theta-v fix/!') (range 10))
; (1 0 2 6 12 20 30 42 56 72)
(map fix/! (range 10))
; (1 1 2 6 24 120 720 5040 40320 362880)
` (hopefully the linebreaks are somewhat obvious)

Comment: Indeed, that certainly looks wrong. I don't have a good answer: it looks like your `!'` is right, and like the implementation of `theta-v` matches Wikipedia's. Since it's wrong even for a value as small as 1, you could try evaluating it by hand and see where it goes wrong (where on earth can a zero have come from?).

Comment: agreed, dont have time at the moment. Good tactic.

Comment: Ah, I see. You don't have enough parens in your `theta-v`. In Haskell, or lambda calculus, `((x x) y) z` is the same as `x x y z`, or in long-hand, `(((x x) y) z)`. However, in most lisps the former means "evaluate `((x x) y)`, then throw it away and return `z`.

Comment: Frick... good catch. That was due to an erroneous refactor, i believe.